# Highstock to find number of points datagrouped and resulted in

Tags: highcharts

I want to display in chart if datagrouping is done how many data points received and after grouping how many points are shown ie No:of datapoints receieved/No:of points after grouping. Is is possible in Highstock.

Thanks,
Senthil

Comment: What have you tried if anything thus far? Please add any additional info to help others with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not available in dataGrouping, but you can prepare your own grouping function which will return this parameters.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.area.dataGrouping.approximation